# Using Beautiful Soup in Python but getting partial source code / only the end portion of the source code

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

So I am new to BeautifulSoup and I have been looking at different sources of information to learn more and find a solution, but I am stuck. I am trying to pull the source code from this [wikipedia site](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Frecuentes-(1-1000)-Subt%C3%ADtulos_de_pel%C3%ADculas) but I get just a portion of the source code, only the the last third part of it or so... thus, I am missing the first 2/3 of the source code. No clue what is that I am doing wrong. Here is the code I am using in Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

corpus_codigo = requests.get("https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Frecuentes-(1-1000)-Subt%C3%ADtulos_de_pel%C3%ADculas").text

corpus_soup = BeautifulSoup(corpus_codigo, features = 'lxml')

print(corpus_soup.prettify())
```

I only get lines 7042 thru 7225... so in reality I am missing much more than 2/3 now that I see it in detail... any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please post the expected output? I just tried the code above and it seems to be working fine. I'm getting the same contents I get via browser and I couldn't see any part missing when using ```requests```.

Comment: I can't put the resulting code... there is a character limit... but it begins on line 7042 thru 7225 (up to the end of the source code.) So everything from line 1 thru 7041 is missing...

Comment: So you are saying that ```requests.get()``` is not giving you the full html page from that link? How are you comparing the output? I tried it here a few times now and I'm always able to get the full page, no matter what. I get the same result via browser, ```requests.get()``` and ```wget``` on the command prompt.

Comment: I consistently get a portion of the source code. I check in the browser and I see the source code and see that what I pull using requests.get() is just a portion of it, usually towards the end of the source code...

Comment: What's the result of ```corpus_soup.prettify().count('\n')```? I'm  getting ```13534``` consistently. Maybe it is a bad proxy between you and that site.

Comment: I am also getting 13534... not sure what that means in this case because I am still missing code. Sorry, this is very confusing and I am new to Python and BeautifulSoup...

Comment: That is exactly the number of lines the page has. If you are getting that, it means the page you are retrieving IS the full version. No lines are missing.

Comment: Well, I am really lost here. I checked the code, I just don't have 13534 lines, not in a million years, I am missing code regardless of what the counter says, and this happens with other websites that I've tried, the are parts of the code that are not pulled into Python, particularly the tables, either they aren't there altogether or just a portion of it, very frustrating. Don't really know what else to do. I spent too many hours on this already. This is for a project in my masters but I'll have to skip this part and take the hit and move on. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Do you have ```tmate``` on your machine? I can share a session from my machine with you and then we can figure it out what is going on. My guess is that you're interpreting the output wrong. :-)

Comment: I don't have  tmate but I'll get it. When/what time would work for you? I am in Spain so I am ahead at this moment 5 hrs with respect to Eastern US time.

Comment: I'm in São Paulo, Brazil, so you are 4 hours ahead of me. I guess sometime around 14h00, your time, will work good for me. Just let me know if that works. I'm looking for a way a to move this to a chat.

Comment: I KNOW WHAT'S WRONG... I can't believe it, but the problem is that the default number of lines I can see in Spyder was set to 500!!! Hence the reason why  I could only see the last part of the code... what a waste of time, I just realized this and I am so upset... anyway, thank you for the help, hope this helps someone else.

Comment: No worries. I was suspecting of something wrong anywhere else anyway.